# Create a .tar.bz2 file Linux

Tags: linux, compression, tar

On my Linux machine, I wish to create a .tar.bz2 file of a certain folder. Once I place myself in that folder (in the terminal), what do I type in the terminal command line to place the compressed folder in the home directory of my machine?

Let's say I am in the folder /home/user/folder. In the folder "folder" are several files (txt, .c etc). How do I compress that folder of type .tar.bz2 and place it in my /home directory?

In the /home/user/folder, I've tried `sudo tar -cvjSf folder.tar.bz2` but get an error:

> tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive

Comment: See also: [bash: /bin/tar: Argument list too long when compressing many files with tar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23817787/562769)

Comment: For those wondering - `c` = create, `v` = verbose, `j` = bz2 compression, `S` = sparse efficiency, `f` = output file name. I don't know exactly what `S` does, this is just a list from the man page

Comment: Don't use `sudo` for that unless you really have to.

Comment: I'm afraid the `S` doesn't exit anymore

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You are not indicating what to include in the archive.

Go one level outside your folder and try:

```
sudo tar -cvjSf folder.tar.bz2 folder
```

Or from the same folder try

```
sudo tar -cvjSf folder.tar.bz2 *
```

Comment: Just beware that if you use the second option, * does not include hidden files in your current folder (starting with a fullstop character). So the first option is better since it will include hidden files.

Comment: Hey, you might change the '*' for '.' in the second option to also include hidden files.

Comment: OpenBSD does not have the '`S`' option, FreeBSD has got it instead but only with 'extract' option, so the best way should be `tar cvjf`

Comment: Why is `sudo` necessary?

Comment: @jewbix.cube It is probably not. `sudo` was present in the question.

Answer (score 13):

Try this from different folder:

```
sudo tar -cvjSf folder.tar.bz2 folder/*
```

Answer (score -4):

```
tar cvzf file.tar.gz *.c OR tar cvzf file.tar.gz *
```

for more read this article https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tar-command-linux-examples/