# bash: /bin/tar: Argument list too long when compressing many files with tar

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I am trying compress files from an archive with the command

```
tar -czvf compress_file.tar.gz $(cat file_list.txt)
```

And I have an error

```
-bash: /bin/tar: Argument list too long
```

The files numbers is too long, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use the "-T" option to pass a file to tar that contains the filenames to tar up.

```
tar -czv -T file_list.txt -f tarball.tar.gz
```

Comment: For people looking how to create the list of file to begin with, and only delete said files that were `tar`'d see this example: https://major.io/2007/07/05/bintar-argument-list-too-long/

Comment: This is how I create the file list: find ./ -iname "\*part_of_filename\*" > file_list.txt

Answer (score 12):

and how to make list of files to tar up:
first create the list of files to tar up

```
ls > temp
```

then

```
tar cvzf dicionario_ultra.tgz -X FILE -T temp
```

and finally

```
rm temp
```

Comment: What is the ‘-X FILE’ part do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` to avoid the issue, it will list the files under current folder and the `-print` will trigger the tar with newline
`find . -type f -print | tar -cvf somefile.tar -T -`